# How to gather `DataFrame.columns` & `Series.name` to one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a variable and it is named `df`.
And its type could be `pd.DataFrame` or `pd.Series`.

I want to get the column of `df`.

For `pd.DataFrame`, we can use `df.columns`. And for `pd.Series`, we can use `df.name`.

So are there some methods to gather both together?

I want to find a pythonic method, such as from the top class to bind them up or injecting function.

Anyway, thanks for your answer `:)`.

Comment: I think not exist such method.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is test it by `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(df, pd.Series):
    print (df.name)
else:
    print (df.columns)
```

---

```
if isinstance(df, pd.Series):
    print (df.name)
elif isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
    print (df.columns)
else:
    print ('another')
```

Or by [`Series.ndim`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ndim.html), [`DataFrame.ndim`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ndim.html):

```
if df.ndim == 1:
    print (df.name)
else:
    print (df.columns)
```

---

```
if df.ndim == 1:
    print (df.name)
elif df.ndim == 2:
    print (df.columns)
else:
    print ('another')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea from [sidetable](https://pbpython.com/sidetable.html).

We could try `the pandas accessor API` to fix the problem and even do more just like `sidetable`.

We can get **columns** from `Series` or `DataFrame` by the same API via `xx.cols()`.

```py
import pandas as pd


@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("cols")
@pd.api.extensions.register_series_accessor("cols")
class PandasColumnAccessor:
    def __new__(cls, pd_obj):
        def columns():
            if isinstance(pd_obj, pd.Series):
                return pd_obj.name
            else:
                return pd_obj.columns

        return columns
```